# VBO is incorrect size after resizing with glBufferData()

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I am hoping to create a level of depth system for procedurally generated terrain using 2 sets of vectors and one set of VBOs per object. One set of vectors (`vertexData, vertexNormals, vertexIndices`) has a lot of data in whereas the other set (`lowData, lowNormals, lowIndices`) has much less.

The following code is called when a chunk is loaded, and then when the camera is in/out of range for a high/low resolution model:

```
if (thisLOD == HIGH)
{
    std::cout << "HIGH: ";
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexDataBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexData.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3),&vertexData[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexIndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexIndices.size()*sizeof(unsigned int),&vertexIndices[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexNormalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexNormals.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3),&vertexNormals[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

}
else
{
    std::cout << "LOW: ";
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexDataBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,lowData.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3),&lowData[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexIndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,lowIndices.size()*sizeof(unsigned int),&lowIndices[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vertexNormalBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,lowNormals.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3),&lowNormals[0],GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
glFinish();
GLint s;
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,GL_BUFFER_SIZE,&s);
GLint s2;
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,GL_BUFFER_SIZE,&s2);
std::cout << "New size: " << s <<" | Should Be Size: " << lowNormals.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3) << " or " << vertexNormals.size()*sizeof(glm::vec3) << std::endl;
std::cout << "New index size: " << s2 <<" | Should Be Size: "<<lowIndices.size()*sizeof(unsigned int) << " or " << vertexIndices.size()*sizeof(unsigned int) << std::endl;
```

When filling the buffer for the first time (on chunk load), the function runs as expected, with the correct data put in the VBOs and the correct sizes shown:

```
LOW: New size: 5292 | Should Be Size: 5292 or 1087212
New index size: 9600 | Should Be Size: 9600 or 2160000
```

however when changing the level of depth of a chunk once it has been generated, the reported size of the buffers is completely wrong:

```
HIGH: New size: 0 | Should Be Size: 5292 or 1087212
New index size: 1994090432 | Should Be Size: 9600 or 2160000
```

The first run always works and the second run always fails, regardless of whether the VBOs are initially filled with the high-resolution data or the low-resolution data. when starting with low-resolution data, all of the terrain stays low resolution when some should be high resolution, however, when starting with high resolution first, the terrain that is too far away to be high resolution becomes small slivers which suggest that some data is still being written, or is persisting:
[image]

The vectors certainly have the correct data in them, and are the correct length, so why does this use of `glBufferData` fail?

Comment: insert glGetError after glBufferData calls and check if there is any error returned. This may give You a hint

Comment: @Amadeusz yes, this gives error code 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) for the calls that are not working. still unsure as to why, but its certainly a step in the right direction, thanks

Comment: Can it be related to the use of several gl-contexts?

Comment: Are there any other places where you modify the buffer handles (`vertexDataBuffer`, `indexDataBuffer`, ...)? Insert `glGetError()` after both `glGetBufferParameteriv()` calls. See if it returns any error in non-working pass.

Comment: @Ripi2 YES, the 2nd call for each chunk was in fact being called from a separate thread, in which there was no active OpenGL context. Creating a hidden GLFW window with context sharing, and activating it in this thread solved the problem. [link](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context_guide.html#context_sharing)

Comment: @jcg Remember, that multi-threading in case of OpenGL gives you no gain, since GL is single-threaded by design and all commands are serialized.

Answer (score -1):

Idea: Have you took into account that the VBO and IBO are calculated in byte?

Look at : pretty good tutorial

[image]

Comment: His data consists of `unsigned int`s and `glm::vec3`s, which is a 3-component vector of float. Beside, how is that relevant to the question? Wrong alignment may cause a performance drops or memory operations errors, but here the problem is the reported size of the buffer, which does not have any connection with the actual representation of the data.